# hudson hangs while fetching from git repo

Tags: git, hudson

I set up a build job on Hudson to build a Git project.
Hudson is running from a console not as a service, on Win 2K8 R2 VM server.
Git access is via SSH.
The Job does the clone succesfully, but then hangs (ongoing processing) while it says it is fetching from remote server.
When i check the job workspace, i see that the cloning is compelte as i can see the contents and the non empty .git folder. It just doesnt proceed from there.
Hudson is logged in via the NT user, whose ssh key is added to the server.
Outside of Hudson, on git bash i am able to clone completly without any error.
What could be wrong?

See the console output below. [since 2-3 hours, no error message]

> Started by user my-userid
>   Checkout:workspace / D:\CITool\Hudson\jobs\project1\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1f676cb
>   Using strategy: Default
>   Checkout:workspace / D:\CITool\Hudson\jobs\project1\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1f676cb
>   Cloning the remote Git repository
>   Cloning repository origin
>   Fetching upstream changes from ssh://admin@server.domain.com/project1

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas of where to look for the problem:

- SSH can have all kinds of slow login problems. Try to disable GSSAPI on the client or DNS reverse lookup on the server.
- disk full /quota problem
- What does Hudson do after git clone? Maybe that is where it is actually hanging.

And regarding debugging:

- Can you reproduce the problem in the same environment that Hudson uses? Same machine, same user, and not using the "git bash" because it might have very different environment settings.
- In Hudson, try to get a verbose git output. You might need a custom (commandline) build step instead of SCM step.